# Spring class design with bean inheritance

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dao

## Introduction

Let's assume I'm selling nice two-wheels, bycicles and motorcicles in my shiny new store. I like to keep track of things so I developed a Spring application to back me up, in case I forget things and stuff...

In this application, there is an abstract Vehicule.java class that is extended by two other Java classes representing the concrete objects I'm selling:

Bicycle extends Vehicule
Motorcycle extends Vehicule

When I physically sell a two-wheels, I go to the application and click on a button that sets the two-wheels as sold in the DB.

## Question

**What is a good Spring design for the JSPs, services and DAO to handle best the inheritage from JSP to DAO without duplicating too much stuff?**

I'm looking for the "best practice" design, something **scallable** that **facilitates maintenance**.

## Current leads

### Idea 1

*A specific JSP calls generic Spring Controller's specific method that calls specific Spring Service that calls specific DAO and do the action.*

Should I write a different JSP for each product type? A bicycle JSP and a separate Motorcycle JSP? Each "setSold" button would be directly pointed to the right service.

In that case, what happens if my variety of products grows? Do I need to multiply everything by the number of products I have?

If we assume for instance skateboard, rollers, roller skates and cars, a sketch of the classes and some methods would be:

**JSP**:

- cardetails.jsp
- skateboarddetails.jsp
- rollersdetails.jsp
- rollerskatesdetails.jsp
- bicycledetails.jsp
- motorcycledetails.jsp

**Controller**:

- @Controller class DetailController.java:

  - void setSold(Car car);
  - void setSold(Skateboard skateboard);
  - void setSold(Rollers rollers);
  - void setSold(RollerSkates rollerSkates);
  - void setSold(Bicycle bicycle);
  - void setSold(MotorCycle motorCycle);

**Services**:

- @Service class CarService.java
- @Service class SkateboardService.java
- @Service class RollersService.java
- @Service class RollerSkatesService.java
- @Service class BicycleService.java
- @Service class MotorCycleService.java

**DAO**:

- @Repository class CarDao.java
- @Repository class SkateboardDao.java
- @Repository class RollersDao.java
- @Repository class RollerSkatesDao.java
- @Repository class BicycleDao.java
- @Repository class MotorCycleDao.java

And the list would grow bigger everytime I add a new product type

### Idea 2

*Generic JSP calls generic Spring Controller's generic method that calls generic Spring Service that identifies the type of object and then calls specific Spring Service that will call the specific DAO and do the action.*

Should I write a generic JSP that handles any type of two-wheels and then let the service dispatch the request to the right service? It feels like it's the most scalable way to do things, but I can't come up with a design that looks right for everything.
Finding the specific service for the given product seems somewhat dirty and hard to maintain. My experimental implementations consisted in mapping object class to services or in writing a big switch case that returns the right spring service depending on the object characteristics.

But it looks like this structure is cleaner and more scalable. If more products are added the simple class model becomes:

**JSP**:

- details.jsp

**Controllers**:

- @Controller class DetailController.java:

  - setSold(Vehicule vehicule)

**Services**:

- @Service abstract class VehiculeService.java
- @Service class CarService.java
- @Service class SkateboardService.java
- @Service class RollersService.java
- @Service class RollerSkatesService.java
- @Service class BicycleService.java
- @Service class MotorCycleService.java

**DAO**:

- @Repository abstract class VehiculeDao.java (abstract)
- @Repository class CarDao.java
- @Repository class SkateboardDao.java
- @Repository class RollersDao.java
- @Repository class RollerSkatesDao.java
- @Repository class BicycleDao.java
- @Repository class MotorCycleDao.java

Comment: You can simply save it as an Object and have extra attributes to it. Or you can save the Object details as JSON, for examples books have ISBN. Then in the JSON, ISBN is one of your parameter. This way, you only have to deal with one object in your backend. You can always change the view to add more parameters by yourself or by user. Does this make sense and is your business requirement?

Comment: Yes, but this example is a **very** simplified version of the real problem.
We should assume that the Beans model cannot be changed.

Comment: If that's the case, then the first option doesn't even make sense. And when you are designing a project from ground-up in this manner, then restricting model from start also doesn't make sense unless you are directly saving JSON in DB. I would suggest please think through the question and update accordingly.#

Comment: Yeah I also don't like option 1 very much. But I don't get what you mean by "restricting model from start" in option 2, in the MySQL DB, there is one table per object (i.e. tables BICYCLE, MOTORCYCLE).
Anyway, I'm thinking through this and can't see any other option for now. I'll update if I come up with something better.

Comment: You are missing the point, if you want to restrict the model from start, which you shouldn't, first option cannot be used. Secondly. If you try to make it generic, given various attributes, you are going to require a strategy to changing products and there changing specficiations. You cannot have N number of variables, that's why you will need JSON.

Comment: Ok but there are things I cannot modify in the application, which are the Bean structure and the DB used (relational, MySQL). I'm pretty sure there are working services using both and that are doing something similar that are coded correctly.